# Contact's past activities aren't appearing on opportunity

Tags: opportunity, account, contact, activityhistory

I'm having some issues when it comes to activities that are related to contacts, that are *not* appearing on the opportunity said contact is on.

In the specific example that was brought to my attention, I have the following:

Josh is a contact. Josh has items under 'past activities' as recently as nov. 5th, 2018. Josh shows as a contact role, and has the 'primary' box checked, on an Opportunity. That is the only opportunity he's on. On that opportunity the most recent item under past activities is back on 5/23/18.

I'm on LEX as well, just in case that makes a difference. I was *thinking* it could have something to do with allowing users to relate a contact to multiple accounts, but this contact in particular is only related to one. I was also thinking it could be related to not having the "Roll up activities to a contact's primary account" box checked. Again though, my thought process there is this contact is only on one account.

Answer (score 1):

Activities have two "connection" fields, which are called "Name" and "Related To" in the user interface, and `WhoId` and `WhatId` under the hood.

The `WhoId` is always a person - a Contact or Lead. If Shared Activities is turned on, it can be more than one Contact. The `WhatId` is something else - a record of any object that is configured to support Activities.

Salesforce automatically performs some "roll-up" type mechanisms to surface Activities in timelines that make intuitive sense. One example of this is the ability to roll Activities up to related Accounts, even if the Account is not the `WhatId` on the Activity.

The full details of how a related Account is determined are documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194177). What's important to know, though, is that this applies only to Accounts. There's no roll-up to Opportunities unless the Opportunity itself is the `WhatId`, the "Related To" entity.

Hence, if you want your Activities to show up on the Opportunity page, you need to relate them to the Opportunity - not just to a Contact that has an Opportunity Contact Role on that Opportunity.

Comment: Hey David - Thank you so much for the in-depth info. In looking at the opportunity I referenced above, I'm seeing emails that I had sent to another contact that's related to this opp. That being said, those emails were sent from inside of Gmail, not the send email global action on the record layout. Why might the emails be showing for that contact, but not for another one, that is listed on this same opp? The activities that aren't showing I _believe_ are emails being sent through Gmail as well. Are you suggesting we use the send Email global action, to send an email to the contact, and leave

Comment: (^^continuing, ran out of characters) leave the "related to" field as the opp? Then it would show who was emailed on the opp's past activities, but would it also show up on the contact record's past activities? @david-reed

Comment: I do not know why Gmail messages might be showing or not showing - I don't use that integration and I'm not familiar with how it relates records.

Comment: Populating the Contact as the Name and the Opportunity as the Related To link will definitely result in the activity showing on both of those records, as well as the Opportunity's Account.

Comment: when you say 'populating the contact as the name', are you referring to sending an email via the send email action, and just making sure the contact is the "to" address? Sorry to be so specific, just want to make sure I get what you're saying.

Comment: I'm really referring to the Activity publishers for Task and Event. I am less familiar with the mechanics of email-related tasks.